# Laravel migrate:fresh not dropping tables, then says nothing to migrate

Tags: laravel, postgresql, database-migration

this is an existing project and I used to use php artisan migrate:fresh command a lot, this morning it suddenly stopped working for no reason.

I am really confused.

When I run migrate:fresh I can see this output in the terminal:

```
  Dropping all tables........................................................ 13ms DONE

   INFO  Nothing to migrate.
```

but it isn't actually dropping anything. All the tables are there and migrations table is populated so it won't do anything more.

Literally nothing has changed and it suddenly stopped working.

Environment details:

```
Laravel 9.52
PHP 8.2
MacOS 13.3.1
Postgres 15.2
```

Any help greatly appreciated

It migrates fine when I delete database and re-create it manually.

So far I have tried clearing cache, dumping autoload, etc. but it makes no difference.

Comment: When it happens, what is the status, i.e. `php artisan migrate:status`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK the solution was simple - I have added the following line to my default connection settings in config/database.php:

```
'schema' => 'public',
```

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel, the `migrate:fresh` command is designed to drop all tables and re-run all migrations from scratch. However, it relies on the migrations table to determine which migrations have been applied.

I think your migrations table are out of sync with the actual state of the database. This can happen if the table was modified manually or if a migration file was modified or deleted without using Laravel's migration system.

To resolve this, you can try manually resetting the migrations table by running the following command:

```php
php artisan migrate:reset
```

After resetting the migrations table, you can attempt to run `migrate:fresh` again.

Hope my answer give you a hint.

Comment: Hi Louis, thanks for the answer but it is not helpful at all. I have been using Laravel for more than 3 years, I know what different migration modes do and in theory migrate:fresh should drop everything regardless of its state and run all migrations from scratch. My problem is that the output says that it dropped all tables when in fact I can see that it didn't drop anything at all.

Comment: Also, I tried creating a fresh copy of the database, then I run php artisan migrate. All worked fine. Immediately after this I run migrate:fresh and it doesn't work. Says it dropped all databases and then 'nothing to migrate'.